# Can catchup be used to backfill failed dag runs in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I have read that Airflows catchup feature applies to task instances that do not yet have a state - i.e. the scheduler will pick up any execution dates where the DAG has not yet ran (starting from the given start_date) - is this correct, and if so, does this mean catchup does not apply to failed DAG runs?

I am looking for a way to backfill any execution dates that failed, rather than not having ran at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [backfill command](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#backfill) options. You could use `rerun-failed-tasks`:

> if set, the backfill will auto-rerun all the failed tasks for the backfill date range instead of throwing exceptions
> Default: False

or `reset-dagruns`:

> if set, the backfill will delete existing backfill-related DAG runs and start anew with fresh, running DAG runs
> Default: False

Also, keep in mind this:

> If reset_dag_run option is used, backfill will first prompt users whether airflow should clear all the previous dag_run and task_instances within the backfill date range. If rerun_failed_tasks is used, backfill will auto re-run the previous failed task instances  within the backfill date range.

Before doing anything like the above, my suggestion is that you try it first  with some dummy DAG or similiar.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, this is really helpful. Do you know if it's possible to execute these commands in the UI? I have airflow deployed in Docker.

Comment: Glad that it helped!. You can't perform explicit backfilling from the UI. Check [the docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#running-the-cli-commands) about how to execute the CLI commands while using Docker Compose or use `docker exec -it container_id bash` to execute bash within the running container.